# I am iterating through a collection of firestore documents. But the function becomes exponentially slow with the number of documents

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Below is my code block. I have iterated through a collection of documents and for each document , I find a same named data (document equivalent of Firebase Realtime database) from Firebase realtime database. If such a data is not found , I remove that document from the original collection. If data is found , I check for the field 'Available'. if it is false , I remove the document , else , I update the field new price to the price data from the realtime database.

Then I find the total of the new prices by iterating through the documents once again and adding all the new price field into a field called 'total'. ( calling addNewPrice() after updation)

This piece of code actually works fine when the collection has few documents. However , when there are more than 7-8 documents , the code becomes painfully too slow in updating total. Is there  hotspots that I am creating that I should avoid ? If this function is deployed as a cloud function , would that solve the latency ? Kindly suggest a solution for this.

(PS : I use Dart language)

```
       Firestore.instance
        .collection('/products')
        .snapshots()
        .listen((snapshot) { snapshot.documents.forEach((doc) async {

          List l;
          var d = await FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().
          child("$databaseID").orderByChild('name').equalTo(doc['name']).once();

           if(d.value == null){

             removeElement(doc);
             }

           else{

             Map<dynamic, dynamic> v = d.value;
             l = v.values.toList();


             if(l[0]['Available'] == false)
             {
               removeElement(doc);
             }

             else{

               Firestore.instance
                 .collection('products').document(doc['name'])
                 .updateData({ 'newPrice' : _list[0]['price'] });

             }

           }

          });
        });


void addNewPrice() async {

    Firestore.instance
        .collection('/products')
        .snapshots()
        .listen((snapshot) async {

      double temp = snapshot.documents.fold(
          0, (tot, doc) => tot + (doc.data['newPrice']);

          await Firestore.instance
              .collection('OrgData').document('Details')
              .updateData({
            'Total': temp
          });

    });
  }
```

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases, each with their own API. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: I actually use both in this code.

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you are benchmarking this code.  It would be helpful if you show some log statements with timing information so we can all see what's slow.